# QGIS pythonpath install packages

Tags: python, pyqgis, installation, python-2.7

I use pyqgis to create standalone GIS apps.

In my system I have only pythonpath from QGIS `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python.exe` I don't have any other python version.
in my installation folder I have a `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27` and `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages` folders.

can I install packages in this folders using `pip` ?

for example If I have install standard python and from cmd use pip then I can easy packages on this folder `C:\Python27`.

Comment: It's not easy answering. Try to install your packages and if there is an error, describe it. Then it might be easier. If you run sys.path in QGIS python console you get the path were QGIS is linked to python

Answer (score 1):

Nathan has a [write-up](https://nathanw.net/2012/12/19/installing-python-setuptools-into-osgeo4w-python/) on how to install python packages for the default version of Python with QGIS, however, it involves using the OSGeo4W shell.

According to him, you must first download and install `easy_install` which you vcan then use to install `pip`, if you want to use `pip`. Further, it seems that the default package save path is `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Scripts` which seems to match your filepath.